# Создайте словарь, в котором ключами будут числа от 1 до 10, а значениями сумма всех чисел от 0 до текущего числа

Tags: python

новичок, пока совсем не понимаю как это сделать(

Comment: вроде же каникулы - что вы все в одно и тоже время стали задачи обучающие кидать? что случилось?

Comment: у студентов нет каникул. но есть удалёнка. даже сегодня в гос праздник в день народного единства.

Answer (score 1):

задачу надо разбить на 3 части

1. в цикле заполнить словарь
2. определить текущее число
3. вычислить сумму дней

заполнить в цикле можно используя цикл `for` и диапазон `range(1, 11)` (т.е. от 1 до 10)

в словарь можно записывать как в массив, т.е.

```
data[ключ] = значение
```

подсчитать сумму чисел можно 3 способами:

1. в лоб через цикл `for` и диапазон `range(0, day + 1)`
2. через функцию `sum` списка содержащего числа от `0` до `day` включительно, а список можно получить превратив диапазон в список `list(диапазон)`
3. через формулу суммы членов арифметической прогрессии `S_n = (a_1 + a_n) * n / 2`

определить текущее число можно

```
import datetime

day = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот. Но можно лучше ))

```
my_dict = dict()
for i in range(1, 11):
    my_dict[i] = sum(range(i+1))

print(my_dict)

{1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 6, 4: 10, 5: 15, 6: 21, 7: 28, 8: 36, 9: 45, 10: 55}
```

Надеюсь я правильно понял, что такое ваше "текущее число"

Answer (score 0):

сумма чисел есть факториал же, для этого даже в стандартной либе есть функция (если нету то каждая вторая пихает свою реализацию факториала), следовательно генератор, или цикл, не имеет особой разницы ответ прост `{A=fact(A)...}`

Comment: факториал это произведение всех числе(`1*2*3*...`), а не сумма

Comment: @Danis не позорь меня DDD но функция summ([]) в питоне способна заменить это